# Different output when using cout + printf vs printf only

Tags: c++, printf, number-formatting, cout

When I'm trying to print a division of a `long long` integer casted to a `float`, I get different output when trying to:

1. use `printf()`.
2. use `std::cout` first before `printf()`.

I'm using the `long long` variable as a sum to a 1000 performance timer results and then average them.  I could probably do some recursion average splitting. But I'll worry that later.

Anyways, here's what is happening.

If I do this:

```
long long sum;

while (j < 1000){
    sum += time_record[j];
    j++;
}

cout << "Average execution time: "<< sum/1000000 << "ms\n";
printf("Average execution time: %f ms\n", (float)sum/1000000);
```

the output I get is:

```
Average execution time: 4ms
Average execution time: 4.197688 ms
```

Now if I try to remove `cout`, I get this output:

```
Average execution time: 140736480.000000 ms
```

What exactly is happening here?

Comment: Usually an indication of UB. Did you initialize `sum`?

Comment: can I know what UB stands for? I didn't initialize sum, but now that I initialized it to 0, I get a wrong output now at both printf and cout: Average execution time: 0ms Average execution time: 0.000081 ms

Comment: Undefined behavior. As to the "wrong output", what are you expecting, and why?

Comment: Have you tried using `sum += (long long)(time_record[j]);`    ? It might solve your problem.

Comment: That you're calculating the average in ms by dividing by one millon, but only have 1000 samples, implies your `time_record` values are in seconds. My guess is that most of them are 0: all of them added together only total 81.  You might need to use a different unit to store the `time_record` values, such as milliseconds instead of seconds, so that the rounding you do when storing them doesn't remove most of their precision and meaning.

Comment: yes, that fixed it Tony. You we're absolutely right and I was using time_record as int and they we're a bunch of zeroes. Changed it to double and it's now fixed.